# MVC url.action with "?" before variable from telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, grid, url-routing, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik MVC grid in my application, trying to open a view using the following:

```
columns.Template(item => Html.Raw("<a href=\"" + Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = item.ID}) + "\">" + item.Name + "</a>")).Title("Go").Width(300);
```

The url I get is:

```
http://localhost:xxx/Controller/Action/54
```

However, the view displays fine, however it does not funcion as it should, the url should be:

```
http://localhost:xxx/Controller/Action?id=54
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was in the path of JW video player:
originall I had it as:

```
 type: "flash", src: "../Video/player.swf"
```

This works well when I send the url as ?id=xx but does not when it is /xx

I change it to:

```
 type: "flash", src: "../../Video/player.swf"
```

This works with both url!!  Don't understand why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work same if your Action method's parameter name is id and you have the normal routing setup.

Comment: I have video files in this view, they don't work.  It has to be ?id=XX.

Comment: did you use visual studio breakpoints to see your action method is executing ? post your action method